# n:m relation table foreign key column unique

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

i have 2 tables

**Pool table**

pid(PK)

---

**Problem table**

number(PK) | name | submit | accept

---

and also have n to m relation table **PoolProblem**

**PoolProblem**

pid(FK from Pool table) | number(FK from Problem table)

---

if i insert tuple in **PoolProblem** like this,

1 | 1

1 | 2

1 | 3

2 | 2 << i want to show error this line, because number column in this line overlaps the second line.

i tried ManyToMany relation, set unique constraint at number column(but error,,,)

how can i solve it?

Comment: Why are you using a many to many relationship then? Sounds like you wish want a foreign key from Pool to Problem.

Comment: You can set `unique=True` for `ForeignKey` from `Problem` model or use `OneToOneField`. It all depends on how you intend to query.